# how to fix some css styles not apply in @media screen and(max-width: 768px)?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**Original CSS**

```css
.form-head {margin: 0 auto;  max-width: 66.5em; padding-bottom: 5.2em; }
.footleft{ max-width: 47.0%;float:left; margin-left: 2.8em; }
.footright{max-width: 46.9%; float:right; padding-bottom: 2%;}
```

**Media query**

```css
@media screen and(max-width: 768px) {
    .form-head { margin: 0 auto !important; max-width: 56.5em !important ; }
    .gradiant{min-width: 50% !important;} 
    .post-contents { max-width: 64.4%; }
    .footleft{float:none; max-width:79%; margin:0 auto;}
    .footright{float:none; max-width:83%; margin:0 auto;}
    .footercontainer {margin: 0 auto; width:94%;}
}
```

The media query styles  does not override the original css . When I add `!important` it's working, but I want to get the media query style, **not include `!important`**.

Comment: Have you got a link to the site?

Comment: No i didnt get the link

Comment: I meant have you got a link to what YOU'RE trying to achieve that isn't working - so we can see what you've done already and see if we can identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document. So if you wanted to make sure that a property always applied, you would add the !important property to the tag.

So Remove **!important**
from .form-header and .gradiant in the media query code.

EDIT : replace

```
@media screen and(max-width: 768px)
```

with

```
@media(max-width: 768px)
```

Comment: if i remove i cant override the native css.

Answer (score 0):

I got the output by not including !important, I just place my native CSS before media query, early mention by @Big Chris..

Comment: and where did the @bigChris mentioned it.

Comment: At fisrt...but now its deleted.